# OnItemClickListener Not working in fragment (Multicolumn ListView)

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, android-listfragment

I need your help!

I have a main activity that contains 2 fragments (one for the header and one for the multicolumn list), one of the fragments is a ListFragments contains a multicolumn ListView, which is boxed in a scrollable view. This ListFragment overrides the onItemClickListener method. I can scroll the view and everything, but when I click on the listview, the listener is not invoked!

I have tried many different solutions, like trying to block focusability for views, but nothing has worked so far. Maybe you guys can help me out.

The parent activity containing the two fragments:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    tools:context=".MainWindow" 
     >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/headerfragment"
        android:name="lindcom.mobile.estock.fragments.ListHeaderFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
         />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/unitlistfragment"
        android:name="lindcom.mobile.estock.fragments.UnitsListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the layout I use for my multicolumn list:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unitsCol1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unitsCol2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.40"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unitsCol3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The above layout is populated in an async task, after I have fetched the data:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    fragment.getActivity().getBaseContext(), this.unitList,
                    R.layout.unit_list_item, new String[] { TAG_OWNER, TAG_NAME,
                            TAG_CONTENT }, new int[] { R.id.unitsCol1, R.id.unitsCol2,
                            R.id.unitsCol3 });


            fragment.setListAdapter(adapter); // Set the adapter to the listFragment
```

Then for the on click listener, I simply override it in the fragment:

```
public class UnitsListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Fetch stuff here

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        String type = l.getItemAtPosition(position).getClass().toString();

        Log.d("Item type was", type);
            // THIS IS NEVER INVOKED :(


    };
}
```

I have tried so many different things, but maybe you guys can see a simple fix to this, something that I might have overlooked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You say you have a ListView in a ScrollView? Is that the case? If so, that's rarely a happy partnership and could be the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your scollview in layout or define it as not focusable then try again

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! It was really that simple. I do not understand how that was needed though, since I define
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
in the scrollView as seen in the OP.

I can't believe it was that simple, and it turns out that I can live without the scrollview anyways, thank you!